# Angular 5 - Auto-reload the HTML page of the specific component at some fixed intervals

Tags: html, angular, timer, reload

The manual solutions for Auto Reloading the HTML page of a specific component:

1. Either by navigating to the HTML page on click.
2. Or calling the `ngOnInit()` of that component on click.

I am doing it manually using a click event from the HTML code as follows:

**HTML Code: app.component.html**

```html
<button (click) = reloadPage()>
```

**TS Code: app.component.ts**

```
reloadPage() {
  // Solution 1:   
   this.router.navigate('localhost:4200/new');

  // Solution 2:
   this.ngOnInit();
}
```

But I need to achieve this automatically. I hope I am clear. The page should auto-reload after some specific interval and call the `ngOnInit()` on each interval.

Answer (score 2):

Add correct call to setInterval anywhere in your call:
`setInterval(() => reloadPage(), 150000);` and inside the method `reloadPage` put the same logic you have for the button.

An example:

---

Just put the `reloadPage` function call inside the constructor:

```
export class SomeComponent {
   constructor() {           
       setInterval(() => this.reloadPage(), 150000);
   }

   reloadPage() {
       // anything your button doeas
   }
}
```

also note, that correct call of `setInterval` would be:

```
setInterval(() => this.reloadPage(), 150000);
```

Note: *My answer just fixes the code you presented. But it seems there is some bigger logical misunderstanding of "reloading page" in angular and using `ngOnInit`*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was not clear at the beginning actually what i need to achieve is to reload the page automatically at some fixed intervals. Since the page will reload at some specific intervals Angular would call the ngOnInit() function at every reload. So this is what i need to achieve.